# Create name shortcut to run application from terminal in Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I have an application X.  I want to be able to type in X anywhere inside terminal to be able to launch application X.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make sure your application is either in one of the directories in your `$PATH` or you create a symbolic link from one of these directories to your application:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/MEMEME/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:...   # let's just assume it's this way
$ ln -s /PATH/TO/MY/APP/X /home/MEMEME/bin/X
$ X              # starts your application
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to invoke **X** application from anywhere inside terminal, **absolute path of X** should be a part of environment variable `PATH`

**Option 1**

Place your application in one of the paths already defined in `PATH` variable. Type `echo $PATH` to list existing list of paths.

**Option 2**

Add following line in your `~/.bashrc` file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/app/X
```

where `/path/to/app/X` should be replaced by an actual path of application X